# how to get maximum length of Text of column in flutter to align in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here i need two kind of alignment...

first column should occupy width based on its child's maximum string length and next column should be align based on decimal..

```
Map<String,dynamic> map={
'FootBall':200.30,
'Hockey':3.30
'Golf':30.400
};
```

and here is code

```
Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          height: 200,
          width: 300,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:
            map.keys.map((e) => Row(
              children: [
              Text(e.toString()),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Text(map[e].toString()),
            ],)).toList()
          ,),
        )
```

I need following way alignment

```
FootBall : 200.30
Hockey   :   3.30
Golf     :  30.400
```

Answer (score 2):

result : [image]

its matter of perspective, instead a column, use a row:

```
class LabelWithDecimal extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, double> map;
  const LabelWithDecimal({super.key, required this.map});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: map.keys.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
        ),
        Column(
          children: map.keys.map((e) => const Text(' : ')).toList(),
        ),
        Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: map.values.map((e) {
              final lStr = e.toString().split('.');
              return lStr.isNotEmpty
                  ? Text(lStr.first)
                  : Text(e.toStringAsFixed(1).split('.').first);
            }).toList()),
        Column(
          children: map.keys.map((e) => const Text('.')).toList(),
        ),
        Column(
            children: map.values.map((e) {
          final lStr = e.toString().split('.');
          return lStr.length > 1
              ? Text(lStr.last)
              : Text(e.toStringAsFixed(1).split('.').last);
        }).toList()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this

You just have to set a `fixed width` to your text widget by wrapping them from `SizedBox`

```
Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 200,
      width: 300,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:
        map.keys.map((e) => Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
          SizedBox(width:60,child: Text(e.toString())),
          const SizedBox(width: 10,),
            const Text(":"),
            const SizedBox(width: 10,),
          SizedBox(width:60,child: Text(map[e].toString())),
        ],)).toList()
      ,),
    );
```

It looks like this
[image]

Comment: No this not what i want....number must be align by decimal

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    Container(
color: Colors.grey,
height: 200,
width: 300,
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children:
map.entries.map((e) => Row(
   children: [
              Text("${e.key} : "),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Text("${e.values}"),
            ],)).toList()
          ,),
        )`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).